# Segue With UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data, uicollectionview

So I have a TableViewController with a CollectionView and a custom Cell, but I want to prepare a segue from that CollectionView to a TableView.

I tried this:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if segue.identifier == "drawSegue" {
        let dst = segue.destination as! DrawerViewController

        guard let indexPath = cupCollectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems else{
            return
        }
        dst.cup = cupboards[indexPath.row] as! Cupboard
    }
}
```

But I get an error `Value of type '[IndexPath]' has no member 'row'`. Is there another way to do that? Cause in another project I used this from a tableView to a tableView and it worked...

This is my CollectionView:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
   return cupboards.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cupCell", for: indexPath) as! CupboardCollectionViewCell

    let cupboard = cupboards[indexPath.row]

    cell.cupLabel.text  = cupboard.name

    return cell
}
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `cupCollectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems` is returning an array of IndexPath objects, so instead of accessing a single `IndexPath.row` you're trying to call `Array<IndexPath>.row` which doesn't exist

In your `didSelectCell` when you call the `performSegue`, add your cell as the sender, then you can change it to `let indexPath = cupCollectionView.indexPath(for: sender)`

Comment: Just changed it to `let indexPath = cupCollectionView.indexPath(for: sender as! UICollectionViewCell)` and it looks like it works, Thanks :)